# Do I need AJAX and ASP.NET for what I'm doing?

Tags: asp.net, html, asp-classic

Easy question.  I used to develop websites back in the days of "classic" ASP, and when I'm asked to do a quick and dirty website for family or friends now, I still resort to direct HTML/ASP and some basic CSS and Javascript - I can get the sites up pretty quickly this way.  However, I've had a few requests to design and develop some sites for pay, and thought I should catch up on my web skills. I have been using .NET 3.5, XAML/WPF, etc. for Windows apps, so I'm up on .NET, I'm just behind on the web end.

**To the question:**  If I want to design/code a site that looks identical on all (at least somewhat recent) browsers and platforms, should I be using ASP.NET and AJAX? There might be a little database activity on the site, but not much, so I don't need an enterprise level, multi-tier extendable architecture...  just something that looks good and works on multiple platforms without having to code all variations for each browser.  After looking at all the ASP.NET books at the bookstore, it seems they all focus mostly on data and postback stuff.  Is it still a legit option to use some basic, boring html and javascript with some Flash embedded where needed?

Let me know if I need to clarify the question. Thanks for your advice in advance!

Comment: All great answers. A belated thanks! I've finally moved on into the jQuery/AJAX/CSS/HTML/ASP mix - it's a much more complex, powerful and enjoyable world than it was tweaking ASP files in Notepad!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with [Aaron Daniels' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2035868/do-i-need-ajax-and-asp-net-for-what-im-doing/2035878#2035878) about learning jQuery.  jQuery helps a lot with cross-browser compatibility in JavaScript and some CSS-based effects.

However, you should also look into ensuring your site uses well-formed, valid HTML, and doesn't use too many CSS 2+ features.  This should ensure that your site is standards compliant, which will mean it will play well with Firefox, Safari, Opera, and even later versions of IE to an extent.  You will still need to do manual tweaking for IE - it's been too broken for too long for MS to be able to fix it properly in one go - so look into [conditional comments](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html) for applying a separate stylesheet for IE users.

AJAX is a handy technology for "desktopifying" your web app.  It provides a mechanism for asynchronous callbacks to the web server, so you can pass data to and fro without reloading the page in the browser window.  This is how the voting buttons work on StackOverflow, for example.

Lastly, ASP.NET doesn't really have much effect on the end user's experience in terms of the look and feel of the site.  It is a server technology that provides for writing complex applications to be delivered over the web to a browser.  Having said that, MS have put in some extra goodies to make working with AJAX a little easier.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 3):

Your question is more loaded than you think, but let me try to address a few points that I think are relevant.

First, how a site looks is almost completely dependent on the HTML/CSS you use and how you code the front end of the site and only slightly dependent on the server technology. So if you want your site to function across browsers and platforms, learn to code following [web standards, with semantic markup](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321616952). (Search on those terms for more info).

Also, ASP.NET comes in two flavors now: ASP.NET MVC and normal ASP.NET. I highly recommend, if you are going to get into ASP.NET, that you follow the MVC platform. It closely follows similar technologies (like Ruby on Rails) and will make the transition to other MVC platforms easier on you. Also, the MVC platform doesn't try to output as much pre-made HTML as straight ASP.NET will when you use their "drag and drop" controls.

Secondly, it really depends on the sites you are building, but straight JS (or JS + [jQuery](http://jquery.com)), CSS, and HTML -- and please don't use Flash unless you are embedding a video -- will actually work for a number of basic sites. If you need some things to happen on the server, PHP makes for a great platform. If you are working with advanced database access, and program flow, and since you are already familiar with .NET, then stick with it... MS has some great tools and resources to help you out.

Finally, a lot of developers use a favorite CMS or blogging platform as the backend of simple sites that still need the ability to manage the content easily. [Expression Engine](http://expressionengine.com/) (CMS) and [WordPress](http://wordpress.org) (Blog/Lite-CMS) are often used (both PHP based) but there are tons out there.

Good luck stepping up your game!

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend learning [jQuery](http://jquery.com/). This will give you a browser independent abstraction for your JavaScript.

ASP.NET controls will render it's controls in a browser independent way, but that doesn't mean your site will automagically be browser independent. You still need to know how elements are rendered differently in different browsers.

I'd also recommend using a [CSS Reset](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/reset/) sheet as a starting point for your CSS.

All in all, if you've been developing old school ASP, you'll probably really love ASP.NET as it will save you a lot of time and looping. You may want to jump right in to [ASP.NET MVC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd394709.aspx) too.

To the root of your question, I'd learn ASP.NET if you're doing anything more than a simple brochure site. If you have .NET experience, and classic web development experience, then learning ASP.NET is not going to be a big hurdle and will be well worth the effort.